# 'Job' object has no attribute 'Wednesday' error when scheduling event

Tags: python, autologin

I tried to make it as easy as possible to understand, I have no backgound in IT, I am doing this auto login program to join my own classes. Can anyone tell me why its not working?

The error is this :

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omiceyo/PycharmProjects/datetimepractice/main.py", line 79, in <module>
    Wednesday()
  File "/home/omiceyo/PycharmProjects/datetimepractice/main.py", line 56, in Wednesday
    schedule.every().Wednesday.at(Class).do(join_meeting(666666666))
AttributeError: 'Job' object has no attribute 'Wednesday' "
```

Here is my code:

```
import datetime
import schedule
import subprocess
import pyautogui
import time


#Define join meeting

def join_meeting(meetingid):
    # open Tencent Meeting windows 10
    subprocess.call(["C:\Program Files (x86)\Tencent\WeMeet\wemeetapp.exe"])
    # 5 secs wait for lag
    time.sleep(5)
    # Click join button
    join_button = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Tencent_meeting_join_button.png')
    pyautogui.moveTo(join_button)
    pyautogui.click()
    # Putting in the Meeting ID
    Id_button = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Tencent_meeting_id.png')
    pyautogui.moveTo(Id_button)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.write(meetingid)
    # Disable mic
    mic_button = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('mic_button.png')
    pyautogui.moveTo(mic_button)
    pyautogui.click()
    # time.sleep(4)
    # Joining the meeting
    Meeting_button = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Join_meeting.png')
    pyautogui.moveTo(Meeting_button)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(4)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    

#Class times
Class = "10:00"
Class2= "14:00"
Class3= "16:00"
Class4= "19:00"
Test= "18:25"

#Define weekdays

def Monday():
    schedule.every().Monday.at(Class2).do(join_meeting(6666666))

def Tuesday():
    schedule.every().Tuesday.at(Class3).do(join_meeting(6666666))

def Wednesday():
    schedule.every().Wednesday.at(Class).do(join_meeting(666666666))
    schedule.every().Wednesday.at(Class2).do(join_meeting(66666666))
    schedule.every().Wednesday.at(Test).do(join_meeting(6666666666))

def Thursday():
    schedule.every().Thursday.at(Class4).do(join_meeting(666666666))

def Friday():
    schedule.every().Friday.at(Class4).do(join_meeting(66666666))

def Saturday():
    print("Its saturday")

Date = datetime.datetime.now()
Today = (Date.strftime("%a"))


if Today=="Mon":
    Monday()
elif Today=="Tue":
    Tuesday()
elif Today=="Wed":
    Wednesday()
elif Today=="Thu":
    Thursday()
elif Today=="Fri":
    Friday()
elif Today=="Sat":
    Saturday()
else:
    print("Today is sunday")

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(60)
I put this just below the schedules for my class but the program still doesnt launch.

Comment: check [docs](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/), you are using capital letter in Wednesday (all days)

Comment: It's `every().wednesday`, not `Wednesday`...

Comment: yes this part has been fixed thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check the capitalization for the days of the week per their [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/).

`wednesday` will get called now but will run into a type error associated with `join_meeting(meetingID)`:

```
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
```

A quick resolution to the `TypeError` is to not pass the `meetingid` through the scheduler and define it else where, example:

```
schedule.every().wednesday.at(Class2).do(join_meeting)
```

Also, the `while` loop is indented too far and won't run.

Comment: Yep thats exactly what happened... How do i fix the TypeError must be callable? And it should actually call the 'test' (third entry).... 
I brought the while loop back in

Edit : Oh you mean create a lot of join_meeting functions instead of only 1 and give each of them a specific ID to work with?

Comment: Thank you, i went up and searched a bit and how to create different functions for all of them. It worked ! My script is taking shape! Thanks again!!